# Obtaining a matrix from GAP directly in TeX

Tags: matrices, gap

In GAP one obtains a matrix in the following way as an output:

```
[ [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

This matrix is given as a list of lists (which are the row vectors).

Question: Is there a direct way to paste this GAP output of a matrix directly into a TeX file and obtain the matrix in TeX?

The motivation for this question is that sometimes one gets very large (like 40 times 40) matrices from GAP as output and it would be nice when one can directly paste such GAP-ouput into TeX to obtain the matrix in LaTeX.

Comment: I was once doing something like this, and I ended up simply writing a python script that would take a text file with GAP-format matrices and yielded LaTeX code. I think this might be a better solution than a LaTeX macro, at least when you do plan to re-use the code (or do any nontrivial amount of editing), but don't plan to re-use the matrices within GAP. The best solution would probably be to get GAP to output latex code on its own, but I don't know if it can do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\def\gapmatrix[{\begin{pmatrix}
\gaprows}
\def\gaprows#1[#2]#3{%
\gapcell#2\gapendrow,\ifx]#3\end{pmatrix}\else\afterfi\\\gaprows\fi}

\def\afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}
\def\gapcell#1,{#1\uppercase{&}\gapcell}
\def\gapendrow#1\gapcell{}
\begin{document}


\[
\gapmatrix
[ [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

### GAP Package `typeset`

Version 1.0 release: 2022-11-11
Repository: https://github.com/gap-packages/typeset

This package allows to generate TeX output in GAP for pasting in TeX (similar to `TeXForm` in Mathematica).

Example:

```
gap> LoadPackage("typeset");
gap> x := [ [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ];;
gap> Typeset(x);
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)
```

### Optional: Call GAP code within TeX document

If you want to automate the insertion step into the LaTeX document,
it is possible to run GAP Code from a TeX document. Following CTAN packages target this functionality (CTAN Topics Callback, Exec foreign, External code)

- [`robust-externalize`](https://ctan.org/pkg/robust-externalize) (see also Github discussion [#7](https://github.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize/discussions/7))
- [`texsurgery`](https://ctan.org/pkg/texsurgery) with [JupyterKernel GAP package](https://github.com/gap-packages/JupyterKernel)
- [`runcode`](https://ctan.org/pkg/runcode)
- [`hvextern`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hvextern)
- [`pythontex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pythontex)
- [`memoize`](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoize)

#### Minimal Example with `texsurgery`

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[gap-4]{texsurgery} % specify kernel

\begin{document}

% \begin{equation} % triggers many errors on first run
% Assuming GAP package "typeset" is autoloaded by gap.
\begin{run}
Print("\\begin{equation}\n");
Typeset([ [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ]);
Print("\\end{equation}\n");
\end{run}
% \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

```
❯ pipenv run texsurgery texsurgery-typeset.tex -pdf
GAP Jupyter Kernel Starting using gap
true
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./texsurgery-typeset.pdf.temp.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-10-10>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./texsurgery-typeset.pdf.temp.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/
map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./texsurgery-typeset.pdf.temp.aux) )</usr/local
/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb></usr/local/
texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on texsurgery-typeset.pdf.temp.pdf (1 page, 18009 bytes).
Transcript written on texsurgery-typeset.pdf.temp.log.
```

PDF:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A different approach (less sneaky than David's)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\gapmatrix}{sO{p}m}
 {% #2 = fences, #3 = data
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% small matrix
    \mare_gapmatrix:nn { #2small } { #3 }
   }
   {% normal size
    \mare_gapmatrix:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__mare_gapmatrix_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__mare_gapmatrix_rows_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_from_clist:Nn { NV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mare_gapmatrix:nn
 {
  % make sure we have no spaces at either end
  \tl_set:Nn \l__mare_gapmatrix_body_tl { #2 }
  % remove the outer brackets
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A\s*\[ (.*) \] \s*\Z } { \1 } \l__mare_gapmatrix_body_tl
  % replace [...] with {...}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \[(.*?)\] } { \{\1\} } \l__mare_gapmatrix_body_tl
  % split into a sequence of rows
  \seq_set_from_clist:NV \l__mare_gapmatrix_rows_seq \l__mare_gapmatrix_body_tl
  % now we can typeset
  \begin{#1matrix}
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__mare_gapmatrix_rows_seq \__mare_gapmatrix_row:n
  \end{#1matrix}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mare_gapmatrix_row:n
 {
  \clist_use:nn { #1 } { & } \\
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\gapmatrix{[ [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ]}
\gapmatrix[b]{[ [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ]}
\gapmatrix*{[ [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ]}
\gapmatrix*[b]{[ [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ]}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: IMHO, this approach seems to me much more sneaky than David's.

Answer (score 2):

### GAP Interface in Sage, Sage method `latex(obj)` & LaTeX package `sagetex`

For installation of `sagetex` see https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/sagetex.html#make-sagetex-known-to-tex

It is pointed out that the CTAN version and the version of `sagetex.sty` distributed with TeXLive might be incompatible with your version of Sage and hence the installation of `sagetex.sty` should be done manually using the version distributed with Sage itself:

```
SAGE_ROOT/venv/share/texmf/tex/latex/sagetex/sagetex.sty
```

For me `SAGE_ROOT` is

```
❯ sage -c "print(SAGE_ROOT)"
/Applications/SageMath-10-0.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sage.framework/Versions/10.0
```

Now how the usage looks like:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sage{matrix(gap('[ [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] ]').sage())}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note, you do not have to call `latex(obj)` yourself: the`\sage` command does this for you. `\sagestr{}` does not do it.

In this particular case, the call to `gap('gap code').sage()` would not be necessary since the matrix notation in GAP and in Sage (Python) coincide. But the point of the question is how to insert into a TeX document GAP code (GAP matrix) and get a proper typeset result in LaTeX. This should illustrate this possibility.